# Is the Color Ramp node clamped by default?

Tags: mathematics

So I've been doing some homework on the difference between the Color Ramp node and the Map Range node.

From what I understand, the *From Min* and *From Max* inputs of the MR correspond to the *Pos* value of the CR. For the CR, the range of the *Pos* is 0 to 1, whereas the range of MR's *From Min* and *From Max* is...unlimited so to speak (Correct me if I'm wrong please).

Then, the *To Min* and *To Max* inputs of the MR corresponds to the *Value* slider on the CR. For the CR, the range of the *Value* slider is 0 to infinity (Can type in value larger than 1), and the range of MR's *To Min* and *To Max* is unlimited again.

We can clamp the MR so that the result is within the *To Min* and *To Max* range. Since there is no option to clamp on the CR, is it clamped and if so what is the range?

Edit : So i did some testing and seems to me that the upper limit of the range can be any value?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yep, it is clamped, you are right. 0-1 is the range. And it is easy to check, why are you asking?

Comment: @Crantisz why is the upper limit 1 if we can input a value larger than 1 in the colour stop? sorry just a tad bit confused

Comment: It's because value 1 equals white color and 0 equals black. So if you plug in BW texture it will perfectly match the color range of possible colors.

Comment: You can set a value above 1 in the different color channels though, if you manually type it.

Comment: @Crantisz edited my post, is it correct for me to say that the clamped range is from 0 to any value? I still don't get why its 0 to 1 when we can input a value larger than 1

Comment: In the pictures, shouldn't the range be from 0 to 2 then? The generated coordinates go from 0 to 1 in the x-direction, when x = 0.8 i have set the output to be 2. So when x = 1, the output should be 2.5 but since its clamped, it remains at 2.

Answer (score 2):

I see now, what is a problem.

So in **ColorRamp** values clumped initially. You can input any values from 0 to 1, but if value higher than 1, it will be 1.

For example, I've added multiply by two to your setup and, as you see, input has been enlarged from 0..1 to 0..2, but all values from 1 to 2 becomes solid color.

[image]

So since Blender has no limits in colors, and you can set any color larger than 1, you can set it, but in will correspond to value in range 0..1.

On the other side, such nodes as **RGB curves** haven't this limit, even if it graphically clumped to 0..1 range. RGB node can interpolate curve out of 0..1 range instead of clamping value:

[image]